# Need help using John Resig’s Simple Javascript Inheritance

Tags: javascript

John Resig’s Simple Javascript Inheritance: http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/

I tried to do such thing:

```
var SomeClass = Class.extend({
    init: function() {
        var someFunction = function() {
            alert(this.someVariable);
        };

        someFunction(); // should alert "someString"
    },

    someVariable: "SomeString"
});

var someClass = new SomeClass();
```

This should alert "someString", but it doesn't because inside the closure function **someFunction**, the value of **this** doesn't refers to the class, it is changed. **That makes me unable to get access to the properties and functions of the class inside a closure function.**

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't think we need a john-resig tag!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe your problem lies in what "this" refers to. "this" is referring to the function in this case, not the object. What you want is probably:

```
var SomeClass = Class.extend({
    init: function() {
        var self = this;
        var someFunction = function() {
            alert(self.someVariable);
        };

        someFunction(); // should alert "someString"
    },

    someVariable: "SomeString"
});

var someClass = new SomeClass();
```

**VERY LATE EDIT**: See also:

- $.proxy - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/
- _.bind - http://underscorejs.org/#bind

Comment: That's what I actually use, but I came here because I search for other method. Using this method makes me write **var self = this;** like 20 times in a page :\

Comment: You could do something like this: http://www.sitecrafting.com/blog/underscore-trick